# R + FE Regression with many fixed effects where I extract the fe coefficients and standard errors

Tags: r, regression, large-data

I have a dataset with around 2 million individiuals. A simplified version of the dataset contains three types of variables: (1) dependent variable (y), (2) covariates (x1, x2), (3) regional fixed effects (reg, around 2000 thousand).

(For a second regression at the regional level) I need to extract the regional fixed effects and their standard errors. The main problem is that my computer gets stuck, apparently because of a lack of memory (I have 16GB, 4-core macbook pro) and at the moment I don't have access to a more powerful machine.

Strategies used:

1. The simple `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + reg,data=DT)` gets stuck

   - I've tried reducing the number of regional dummies (e.g. dropping individuals in different regions) and this works when I have around 500 dummies. Nonetheless this implies dropping half of my dataset.
2. Using lm_robust:

- `lm_robust(y ~ x1 + x2, fixed_effects= ~ reg, se_type='stata',data = DT)` works, is relatively fast, gives the coefficients of the fixed effects (fixed_effects), but not the standard errors
- `lm_robust(y ~ x1 + x2 + reg, se_type='stata',data = DT)` gives me the fixed effects coefficients and standard errors, BUT gets stuck when I use more than 500 regions

3. Using either felm or feols

   - `felm(y ~ x1 + x2 | reg, data=DT)`
   - `feols(y ~ x1 + x2 | reg, data=DT)`

   Both methods work, are very fast, BUT DON'T HAVE IN THE OUTPUT THE FE COEFFICIENTS AND STANDARD ERRORS

One strategy I've considered is to use felm/feols and use the outputs "residuals" (residuals of the full system, with dummies) and "r.residuals" (residuals resulting from predicting without the dummies) to back out the regional residuals (i.e. for region i,  hat(reg)_i = (y-hat(b1)*x1 - hat(b2)*x2 - hat(reg_i)) - (y-hat(b1)*x1 - hat(b2)*x2 ). The problem with this is that I wouldn't get the standard error. One solution for this would be to use bootstrapping to compute the standard errors. This should work (I haven't tried it yet), but it seems to be too convoluted.

Comment: Try the biglm package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I ran into the same type of problems. When there are many fixed effects my computer can't handle it

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested I ended up computing the standard errors by bootstrapping.
My data contains four types of variables: (1) dependent variable (y), (2) covariates (x1, x2), (3) regional fixed effects (reg, around 2000 thousand) and a group variable (clus).

An additional complication that I had is that I needed to compute clustered standard errors (clus is the group variable). Here is the code that I used.

```
# Construct variable with all the cluster groups. This will be used later to create the bootstrap samples
DT[, `:=` (reg = as.factor(reg),clus = as.factor(clus)) ]
clusters <- as.data.table(table(DT$clus))

# To speed up the process I parallelize my code
cores <- detectCores() -1
registerDoParallel(cores)
b <- 7000   # Number of bootstrap repetitions

set.seed(123456)
foreach (i=1:b, .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
  # Create a sample with replacement, where the sample is constructed taken into account the clustered nature of the data
  units <- sample(clusters[[1]], size = nrow(clusters), replace=T)
  DT_b <- DT_res[as.character(units), on = "occind",allow.cartesian=TRUE]
  
  # Use felm to perform the regression. This way of doing it absorbs the fe, and thus can deal with a lot of fixed effects
  A <- felm(y ~ x1 + x2 | reg | 0 | clus , data=DT_b)

  # Extract the fixed effects using getfe
  A_fe <- as.data.table(getfe(A)[c("idx","effect")])
  setnames(A_fe,c(1,2),c("rn","coef"))
  A <- as.data.table(A[c("coefficients")],keep.rownames=TRUE)
  setnames(A,c(1,2),c("rn","coef"))

  A <- rbind(A,A_fe,fill=TRUE)
} -> coef.parallel
```

The `coef.parallel` dataset looks like this

```
rn       coef
x1       -0.123
x2       -0.321
reg1     0.0012
reg2     0.003
...
reg2000  -1.2
...
...
x1       0.124
x2       0.521
reg1     0.032
reg2     0.03
...
reg2000  -0.9
```

The next step is simply to compute the mean over each variable (rn) and the standard error

```
# Compute the bootstrap estimate and clustered standard errors
estimation.bootstrap.parallelized <- coef.parallel[,.(coef.b=mean(coef),se.b=sd(coef,na.rm=TRUE)),by="rn"]
```

The `estimation.bootstrap.parallelized` dataset looks like this

```
rn       coef.b   se.b
x1       -0.208   0.0032
x2       -0.321   0.123
reg1     0.0012   0.00041
reg2     0.003    0.00021
...
reg2000  -0.945     0.32
```